# How get total and name to field with query builder in formtype symfony

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I want to create a select field with referece of my types available.

I have 3 entity. Post, Types[typebase_id, count=0], TypesBase[name,quantity].

I want to display => Choices =>

- TypeA (3)
- TypeB (12)

1- I need to get TypeBase Name.

2- I need to group by Types (Typebase_id and count=0)

3- The selected value will be Typebase_id of Types entity.

I have this in my formtype.

```
$builder->add('types', 'entity', array(
                    'class' => 'PostBundle:Types',
                    'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) use ($user) {
                        return $er->createQueryBuilder('w')
                            ->where("w.user = :user")
                            ->setParameter('user', $user)
                            ->andWhere("w.active = :active")
                            ->setParameter('active', 0);
                    },
                ));
```

I try __toString in Types, but i cant get TypeBase Name.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `choice_label` parameter. 
Docs: http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/reference/forms/types/entity.html#choice-label

```
$builder->add('types', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'PostBundle:Types',
    'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) use ($user) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('w')
            ->where("w.user = :user")
            ->setParameter('user', $user)
            ->andWhere("w.active = :active")
            ->setParameter('active', 0);
    },
    'choice_label' => function ($type) {
        return $type->getName();
    }
));
```

Or just: `'choice_label' => 'name'`.

Comment: $type has a reference of TypeBase. With ID setted. But name is null. I want get name of TypeBase.

Comment: Show my Your Base and TypeBase entity.

Comment: And try to add `fetch="EAGER"` to your `BaseType` relation in `Type` entity

Comment: Maybe is wrong example. I want display total posts in categories. With outputting checkboxes in a hierarchy. Similar WP.